# Pass response of one http request to another Synchronously in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I want to Pass response of one http request to another Synchronously ,
Have three conditions to execute one by one  `PreExecute(),OnExecute() and PostExecute()` .

Each of the above will send http request to a URL and returns a json which should be the input to the next module .How to achieve this in Node.js

Comment: We need to see more real code to make a specific suggestion.  Do your three functions return promises?  Do they take a completion callback?  What do you want to do if one of the first two has an error?  Not enough info included yet to write a complete answer.  And, none of this is going to run "synchronously".  Probably what you want is you want the three operations "sequenced" so they happen in serial order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `waterfall` from `async` library. You can work something like this

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
  function (callback) { //PreExecute
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    });
  },
  function (arg1, arg2, callback) { //OnExecute
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
      callback(null, 'three');
    });
  },
  function (arg1, callback) { // PostExecute
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      // arg1 now equals 'three'
      callback(null, 'done');
    });
  }
], function (err, result) { // Finally
  // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. That pretty much did the job. But I had one problem, in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute()only one http req will be sent. But in On execute there are many steps iterated in a loop and each loop will fire a http req, I tried using A nested async.waterfall() function but it is becoming asynchronous. But If I execute the whole thing with one http req for each function(pre,on,post) it is working perfect.

Comment: Consider using `request-promise` library and create an array of promises for each request. Then use `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0):

If each of your three functions returns a promise that is resolved with the result of the async operation, then it's very simple to do using promise chaining:

```
PreExecute(...).then(OnExecute).then(PostExecute).then(result => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // an error occurred
});
```

In this sequence, the resolved result of `PreExecute()` will be passed as a single argument to `OnExecute()` and the resolved result of `OnExecute()` will be passed as a single argument to `PostExecute()` and the resolved result of `PostExecute()` will be passed to the final `.then()` handler.  If an error occurs in any of the three, that error will be passed to the `.catch()` handler.  This is a classic use of Promise chaining to sequence asynchronous operations and to pass data down the chain.

If your functions don't already return a promise, then we need to see exactly how one knows they are done (perhaps using a callback) and they can likely be simply wrapped in a promise to make this structure work.

---

If your `PreExecute()` function follows the node.js asynchronous calling convention and accepts a callback as its last argument that is called with `(err, result)` as the arguments, then you can "promisify" those functions fairly easily with [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).  If they don't have any way for the caller to know when their underlying asynchronous operation is complete, then they have to be fixed in order to offer that.  There is no other way to sequence them if they don't provide a means of knowing when they are complete.